# Can i Zoom form while it is Active

Tags: vb.net, forms

well guys i want to know is there any way i can zoom my form in vb.net.
i could resize the form and byanchoring all controls to left top right bottom i can make it look like zoom. but it is not actually zooming. it is resizing. while font size and other formats are still as same.

also see if anyone can answer my another question..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749877/need-help-doesnt-printform-work-well-on-painted-objects-or-forms

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy way to zoom like this as far as I know.  Fonts in particular have a fixed aspect so you cannot easily make them taller or wider than normal if you are re-sizing your form arbitrarily.

You can force the resize to maintain its aspect ratio, however, and then you could recursively go through all of your controls, identify their types, and scale them appropriately in the Resize event of the form - ie:

```
Public Class Form1
Private lblSize As Single
Private Fwid As Integer
Private Fheight As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
    Me.Height = Fheight * Me.Width / Fwid 
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is Label Then
            Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(ctl, Label)
            Dim nFont As New Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, lblSize * Me.Width / Fwid, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)
            lbl.Font = nFont
        End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Fwid = Me.Width
        Fheight = Me.Height
        lblSize = Label1.Font.Size
    End Sub
End Class
```

You would have to do this for every control type you use.  I only did font size here but you would have to scale the position, etc, as well.  The redraw on this will not be pretty but it would work.  A better alternative might be to go with WPF, which has more tools available to do this sort of thing.

Also, if you have controls within controls (tab pages, groupboxes, etc) you have to use recursion to find them all - something like :

```
Public Shared Function GetAllControlsRecurs(ByVal list As List(Of Control), ByVal parent As Control, ByVal ctrlType As System.Type) As List(Of Control)
   If Parent Is Nothing Then Return list
   If Parent.GetType Is ctrlType Then
            list.Add(Parent)
   End If
   For Each child As Control In Parent.Controls
       GetAllControlsRecurs(list, child, ctrlType)
   Next
   Return list
End Function
```

where you would use the above function like :

```
Dim buttonList As New List(Of Control)
Dim checkboxList As New List(Of Control)
'etc...

For Each ctl As Button In GetAllControlsRecurs(buttonList, Me, GetType(Button))
     ' Do something...
Next

For Each ctl As CheckBox In GetAllControlsRecurs(checkboxList, Me, GetType(CheckBox))
     ' Do Something...
Next
```

Also - accepting answers will probably encourage people to help you.